# Function that returns sums of even numbers from start to end

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a function that sums all even numbers from "Start" to "End".
I have written the following code, and need to use a while loop. When I run the program, it is not returning anything. Thanks for the help.

```
def sum_of_even_num(start,end):
    sum = 0
    while start <= end:
        if(start % 2 == 0):
            sum = sum + start
            start = start + 1
    return sum
print("sum_of_even_num(1,10) =",sum_of_even_num(1,10))
```

Comment: Unindent `start = start + 1
    return sum` so it is outside of your if-statement. Right now it keeps looping without advancing the number. Or you could just do `sum(range(start + start % 2, end + 1, 2))`

Comment: lol it is normal look at "start = start + 1"....you should increase start even if it is odd or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by ensuring start is even to begin with, and then just incrementing it by 2:

```
def sum_of_even_num(start,end):
    sum = 0
    start += start % 2
    while start <= end:
        sum += start
        start += 2
    return sum
```

And the mandatory list comprehension:

```
def sum_of_even_num(start,end):
    return sum(i for i in range(start + (start % 2), end + 1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop, you only add 1 to start when its a even number, but not when its a odd number, so it starts at 1, which is odd and never reaches 2. So move the `start = start + 1` outside the if statement

```
def sum_of_even_num(start,end):
    sum = 0
    while start <= end:
        if(start % 2 == 0):
            sum += start
        start += 1
    return sum
print("sum_of_even_num(1,10) =",sum_of_even_num(1,10))
```